# Array of abstract objects not being filled with following subclass objects

Tags: java, arrays, abstract, aggregation

I have two methods to read process objects from a file and an array of abstract objects. The two methods create objects that are subclasses of the abstract class from the file data.

When I try to populate this array it is filled with null values and I am unsure as to why. If I first initialise a new subclass object with a default constructor it displays the default object but not the object created from the two other methods

```
private static NonMetal processNonMetal (String line, int numEle)
{
    NonMetal nonMetalElement = new NonMetal();
    String[] lineArray = line.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9.]");
    nonMetalElement.setSymbol(lineArray[0+ 5 * numEle]);
    nonMetalElement.setName(lineArray[1 + 5 * numEle]);
    nonMetalElement.setAtomNum(Integer.parseInt(lineArray[2 + 5 * numEle]));
    nonMetalElement.setMass(Double.parseDouble(lineArray[3 + 5 * numEle]));
    char state = lineArray[4 + 5 * numEle].charAt(0);
    nonMetalElement.setState(state);
    return nonMetalElement;
}

private static Metal processMetal (String line, int numEle)
{
    Metal metalElement = new Metal();
    String[] lineArray = line.split("[a-zA-Z0-9.]");
    metalElement.setSymbol(lineArray[0 + 5 * numEle]);
    metalElement.setName(lineArray[1 + 5 * numEle]);
    metalElement.setAtomNum(Integer.parseInt(lineArray[2 + 5 * numEle]));
    metalElement.setMass(Double.parseDouble(lineArray[3 + 5 * numEle]));
    metalElement.setConduct(Double.parseDouble(lineArray[4 + 5 * numEle]));
    return metalElement;
}
```

And the code to populate the array

```
public static void readValues(String fileName)
{
    if (!constructed)
    {
        FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
        InputStreamReader rdr;
        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        String line;
        int lineNum;
        try
        {
            fileStrm = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
            lineNum = 0;
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {

                count = numEle(line);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        lineNum++;
                        if (isMetal(line, i))
                        {
                            elements[lineNum - 1] = new Metal(processMetal(line, i));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            elements[lineNum - 1] = new NonMetal(processNonMetal(line, i));
                        }

                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                    }

                }
                line = bufRdr.readLine();

            }
            fileStrm.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            if(fileStrm != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileStrm.close();

                    constructed = true;
                }
                catch (IOException ex2)
                {
                }
            }
            System.out.print("error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(elements[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Where is elements declared? - 2. Why not do `elements[i]` rather than `elements[lineNum - 1]`? - 3. When you say full of null values, do you mean Metal and NonMetal objects with all null values, or do you literally just mean null? - 4. Why are you doing `new Metal` and `new NonMetal` in `readValues` when you're already being returned an object by `processMetal` and `processNonMetal`?

Comment: I don't think enough code is here for us to help. Could you post the Metal and NonMetal classes, along with their parent class, please?

Comment: A newly constructed array of an object type will have all its values initialized to `null`. Otherwise, you need to explain your problem better and show more code.

Comment: elements is declared privately at the start of the class as size 100. I cant do `elements[i]` because that i is meant to go through the objects on the line because a line can have multiple objects. I've tried with and without `new Metal` and `new NonMetal` in `readValues` and both do not fill the array with the appropriate objects, it just fills with null when i print the array. If I do `elements[lineNum - 1] = new Metal();`

Comment: The Metal and NonMetal classes just have its normal constructors and normal setters/getters with calls to super where necessary. The Element class is the same except its abstract and holds the necessary setters/getters such as `setMass` and `setAtomNum` but omitting `setState` and `getState` because they are nonMetal specific